# How to detect "on Screenshot" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a web app similar to instagram and i want to detect and call a function whenever a user takes the screenshot, is their any way to implement this with javascript?

Comment: There are many ways a user might collect a screenshot without the browser even knowing about it.

Comment: Yes, due to security issues I don't think any browser want to implement such functionality. It's not in the w3 standard for sure.

Comment: Hulu does it see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916474/how-do-you-detect-a-screen-shot-with-js/67916575#67916575

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there is no way to handle a screenshot event through javascript. The screenshot functionality of phones simply has no connection to the browser.